# Assembly 16 bit Fibonacci Series

Tags: assembly, fibonacci, emu8086

What am I doing wrong? This code only generates accurate Fibonacci series up to 13 after that it's giving the wrong value.

**Output**

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 29, 37
```

As its should be `21` after `13` and not the `29`

**Code**

```
org 100h
.data
    num dw 0

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov cx, 15
    mov bx, 1       

    mov si, offset num


fibonacci:
    mov dx, [si] ;dx=0,1,1,2,3
    add [si], bx ;num=1,1,2,3,5 
    mov bx, dx ;bx=0,1,1,2    
    mov di, [si]
    add si,2
    mov [si], di   


    loop fibonacci
main endp
end main

ret
```

Comment: Not sure how emu8086 works but if it's anything like a .com file then do not put your `.data` at the start because you will eventually overwrite your code. Also `ret` should probably be before the `main endp`.

Comment: Change `num dw 0` to `num dw 16 dup (0)` (assuming masm), and as commented by Jester, move the .data segment. to after main. Move the `ret` to before `main endp` .

Comment: Thanks, @rcgldr. It works by changing `num dw 0` to `num dw 16 dup(0)`. Why don't you post it as an answer?